# Suggested feature - simplify migration process

Tags: feature-request, migration, off-topic, moderator-abilities

I am suggesting to add a new feature that simplifies the question migration process.

Requested feature: Adding a "**Migrate**" option next to the "**Close**" option.

---

The migration procedure is described in *[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)*.

Changing the migration process is discussed in *[Considering changing the migration process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371652/considering-changing-the-migration-process)*.

There are many more posts regarding the migration subject... I would like to suggest a different approach.

For migrating a question we have to vote for closing the question. I have a feeling that closing a question has a negative impact on the OP (personally, I am trying to avoid it).

The closing requirement may be the reason for the fact the migrated questions is relatively rare.

In my opinion, question migration should be perceived as a positive action that is meant to help the OP get an answer.

---

My suggestion: Adding a "Migrate" option next to the "Close" option.

- The *Migrate* option should be exposed to the OP (as "single-click migration").
- The *Migrate* option should be exposed to users that have closing permissions.

---

Personal experience and motivation:

Most of the **[FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)**-tagged questions on Stack Overflow are considered "off-topic", because they are questions about tool usage, and are not programming questions. These questions are supposed to be asked on the Super User site.

Most of the users don't know (or don't care), and post the question on the Stack Overflow site. There is a "flood" of FFmpeg-related "off-topic" questions posted on Stack Overflow.

The existing tools are not sufficient for stopping the "flood".

The bottom line is the users are not getting answers to their questions, and the site loses "customers" in the long term.

If we had the tools for a simple migration, we could have migrated the questions and answered them on the Super User site.

Comment: "*Most of the users don't know (or don't care), and post the question on the StackOverflow site.*" and are these unknowledgeable or uncaring questions *good*? As in - not going to be closed on another site?

Comment: Lots of the referred questions are considered nice questions for SuperUser site, but "out of topic" for StackOverflow site. The questions are just "hanged" there (not closed, not answered, not commented). I thought it would be a good idea to migrate the questions and post an answer in SuperUser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Migration is, at its base, a type of closure. The question doesn't get moved and stay open on the source site. There's no real need to separate it from the closure dialog. I could see a reason to do so, if we were desiring to make migration easier, but there really isn't a consensus to make migrating easier or more routine.

Migration is expected to be a *rare* thing. It's only used for questions which are

1. off-topic on the source site,
2. on-topic on the destination site, **and**
3. considered a *good quality* question on the destination site.

Frankly, most users on the source site don't have the experience on the proposed/potential destination site to accurately evaluate (2) or (3). Even moderators on the source site often ask moderators on the proposed destination site if the question is wanted. More often than not, of those proposed migrations that get that far, the question isn't appropriate for the proposed destination site.

Until the question is answered, question OP's can *easily* post a new question on whatever site they feel is appropriate by just copying and pasting the Markdown from their existing question into a new question on the other site. They can then delete their question on the source site. For question OP's, there's nothing magical about being able to migrate vs. just reposting a new question, when there are no answers. It is *substantially* preferred that a question OP repost their question on a site they choose, rather than someone else migrating a question either with or without the question OP's agreement/participation/request.

In general, destination sites don't want it to be easier for users to migrate questions off of Stack Overflow their sites, because they have had substantial experience with poor quality and/or off-topic questions being migrated. There are, of course, exceptions. However, those exceptions are substantially more rare than the general case.  For example, *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)* feels so strongly about not wanting questions migrated from Stack Overflow that they run a bot to inform them in chat of whenever someone on Stack Overflow suggests that a question might be more appropriate on Code Review. They do this so they can be sure to review the question and make it clear that such questions are generally not appropriate for migration.

Overall, making it easier for people other than the question OP to cause a migration would cause more harm and confusion than the way it currently is. Making a system level change to make it easier for question OP's to migrate their questions isn't all that much of a savings in effort on their part, even if it psychologically feels better to migrate rather than copy & paste then delete the original.

In my opinion, we shouldn't do this. Just close the off-topic questions.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the subject. I was not aware of the problems migration raises for the destination site. Do you have any suggestions regarding the subject of convincing the OP to delete the question and posting it elsewhere? A comment that asks the OP to delete and repost seems right only if we promise to post an answer on the other site.

Comment: @Rotem From time to time, I've used a close reason such as: `This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name). However, *be sure to read the on-topic page for the site you select prior to posting*.`

Comment: @Rotem  As I mentioned in my answer, some sites *really* don't want users suggesting to question authors that they go post on another specific site, primarily because most users don't *really* understand the scope and topicality of most other sites. If you're *actually* familiar with another site (i.e. you actively participate there e.g. asking questions, answering, reviewing, etc.), then it could be reasonable for you to suggest a specific other site (e.g. there's at least one moderator of another site that suggests on some SO questions that the question could be posted on their site).

Comment: I have seen questions asking for “the best” programming IDEs migrated to SU. When I confronted the user who suggested that question be posted on SU instead of SO (question was closed on SO) I was told it would be within topic.  Needless to say the reposted question on SU, without any improvements, was eventually closed at SU.

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem unreasonable to separate migration from closure in general, but be careful that adding another parameter to a post means we get more states and we need to determine what happens in them. First, what are the possible states?

Can a question be both closed and "pending migration"? What happens, then, is it still migrated? Does it remain closed after migration? If the other sites don't want the question, do they need to close it, or migrate it back? Maybe both?

If a question is closed, can it be voted for migration, and if a question is pending migration, can there be voted for closure?

I can ask more questions, but at this point I have to ask, for the precise problem your proposal is solving, is this really the best solution? What exactly is missing in the existing tools?

---

> In the bottom line, the users are not getting answers to their questions, and the site loses "customers" in the long term.

> If we had the tools for a simple migration, we could have migrated the questions and answered them on the Super User site.

Why not inform the user that they should delete their question on Stack Overflow and ask it on Super User instead? Sure, you can't force the user to do that, but if they don't want to ask their question elsewhere, why would it be good to force it?

Comment: I realize that the suggested feature as I posted it is not well defined, and not going to be implemented as is. My intension is more about "separate migration from closure", and I don't really know how to solve it correctly. Informing the user that they should delete their question on SO and ask it on SU instead, is almost never work in practice. There is a "flood" of FFmpeg-related question, and in the current state it's not practical to convince all the OPs to delete and ask it on SU.

Comment: So, what you want is mass migration of a tag? Can you not ask on the site-meta whether there can be a one-time move of the tag?

Comment: No, I am not asking for mass migration of a tag. According to the following [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168740/are-ffmpeg-questions-really-off-topic), questions about using the command line tool, are off-topic for SO, but many questions are in topic.

Comment: I see. But would submitting a list of questions for migration and migrating them en mass be a temporary solution?

Comment: It's not how see it. As I see it, migration should be at the same level of closing - no mess migration as no mess closing. The exception is allowing the OP simple migration.